# How to check if the WPF Window is being dragged

Tags: c#, wpf, window, mouseevent

In need to get whether or not my WPF application's Window is currently in the process of being dragged or re-sized. I need to prevent a specific action from happening if this is the case.

I need to check if the window is currently in any situation where the mouse is being held down on the the part of the window that can preposition it.

I am assuming there is  probably some information somewhere on the

```
Application.Current.MainWindow
```

property. Or maybe there is a few events that I need to keep track of to have this information.

Any ideas how I would do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `LocationChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ResizeBegin and ResizeEnd event. They should both fire when the application is being moved, and disable your feature when Begin is called and until End finishes.

EDIT: Just realized this is WPF, in which case check this article: [Determining when a WPF window is being moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552487/determining-when-a-wpf-window-is-being-moved)