# Resize window without showing window contents

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, resize

In Windows you have a setting to "Show window contents while dragging". When this is off you are instead resizing with an outline of the window.

My WPF application has many controls on it, so it is extremely slow to resize. Is there a way to make my application resize by showing only the window outline instead of always updating the contents?

I found this [question regarding WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548479/turn-off-show-window-contents-while-dragging-setting-while-displaying-my-c-sha) but unfortunately I'm not able to adapt it to WPF. I can hook onto the `HwndSource`, but the message numbers may have changed in Windows 10, so the `if` statement in that answer is never entered... or there may be other things at work.

Also, inside the `if` it calls the `WndProc` base after is has changed a system parameter, then resetting the system parameter when it has finished calling it. But calling that method is not an option in WPF as a `Window` object does not have a way to forward the message.

```
public void OnViewLoaded() {
    HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(
        new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    source?.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam,
                              IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
    if (msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND && (wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0) == SC_SIZE) {
        // This if is never entered

        int isDragFullWindow;
        GetSystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDRAGFULLWINDOWS, 0, out isDragFullWindow, 0);

        if (isDragFullWindow != 0)
            SetSystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS, 0, 0, 0);

        // How to call this?
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (isDragFullWindow != 0)
            SetSystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children

Comment: @KoryGill Might very well be. How would you suggest I suspend my main window control before resizing? I don't know which event or message is fired _before_ the resizing takes place.

Comment: As stated, your question is too broad. There's not even a good [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That said, why not just hide the root-level element in the window when resizing starts and show it again when it's over? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552487/determining-when-a-wpf-window-is-being-moved for info about detecting start and finish of resizing.